# new PHPMailer() destroys Session

Tags: php, session, phpmailer

i've got a really curious error in my script, and i can't find the mistake.

I want to send a Email via SMTP on an external Server, for example to a gmail-Server.
After the Email was sent, the script should redirect to itself with an additional Parameter.
The Session-ID is also stored as a $_GET-Parameter. My code is the following:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false; 
    $webmaster_email = "hayo@gmail.com"; 
    $email="hayo@gmail.com"; 
    $name="Simon";
    $mail->From = $webmaster_email;
    $mail->FromName = "Simon";
    $mail->AddAddress($empfaenger, $row['name'] . " " .$row['name']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; 
    $mail->AddAttachment($filename); 
    $mail->IsHTML(false); 
    $mail->Subject = $betreff;
    $mail->Body = $nachricht; 
    $mail->AltBody = $nachricht; 
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
header('Location: http://somedomain.com/somedirectory?sid='.$_GET['sid'].'&step=step2&message=a1');
```

The problem is now, that my Session always gets lost/destroyed, i don't know really what exactly.
The curious thing is: The redirect works when i comment the 
    new PHPMailer(); 
line out.

I'm searching for the problem now several hours...i hope somebody is able to help me.

Greetings,
Simon

Comment: Are you manually maintaining your session with `$_GET['sid']?

Comment: Keep in mind that `http://somedomain.com` is not `http://www.somedomain.com` and sessions won't carry across. Maybe that is your problem?

Comment: Yes, i have to, i haven't implement the system by myself, but it's maintaining the sessions like this.
And Pekka, no it's definetely not the redirect. It works well without generating a PHPMailer-Object...

Comment: YES! now i am facing the exact problem... their is some issue with the new PHPMailer(). Its is destroying the session when send() call.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it, with deleting the line

```
$email="hayo@gmail.com";
```

there was no problem anymore.
Don't know why, but thank you for your help!

Comment: This really doesn't make sense... the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, but in the whole script i haven't got another variable $email or something else. I thought i overwrote a variable or something like this.